# How do I remove a matplotlib fill from my plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was able to add a fill of a triangle onto my plot by following the format:

```
ax.fill([x1, x2, x3], [y1, y2, y3], 'r', alpha = 0.5)
```

But when I want to reuse the graph to show a different dataset, I cannot seem to be able to remove the fill *object*. My plot contains markers, lines and a single fill. **What would be the best way to remove this fill?**

Currently, when I want to reset my graph, I use:

```
EraseMarkers() # To remove markers
for i in ax.get_lines():
    i.remove() # To remove lines
```

I tried use matplotlib's `ax.cla()` function, but this doesn't satisfy my needs as it clears the **entirety** of my plot in which I would like to keep the image that I set as a background and other settings. Here is the code for setting up my plot:

```
fig = Figure(figsize = (9, 3.8), dpi = 100)
img = plt.imread('Rink2.png')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
img = ax.imshow(img, extent=[-100, 100, -42.5, 42.5])
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axis('off')
```

I'd love to know an easier way to remove **all plotted objects** (Markers, lines & fill) without erasing my background and settings. *Or* just a way to remove the fill.

Comment: Most of the time I'd just create a whole new figure containing just the things I want. Why are you removing things from an existing plot?  I.e. it sounds like you're using the API incorrectly

Comment: It is possible that I am. The figure itself is in a Tkinter window as I'm creating somewhat of an app to view different graphs based on variables that are selected from Tkinter buttons.

Comment: thanks for the clarification!  I guess it would depend on whether it makes sense for things like the user's zoom/panning to be maintained when you change what's shown.  if you want everything to reset then create a new figure, if it makes sense for the user to keep the same viewport then I'd start adding/removing `Artist`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to remove an element arbitrary element `A` from a plot by using `A.remove()`.
To do that, when you call `ax.fill` you can store the return of this function to a variable, as

```
filled = ax.fill([x1, x2, x3], [y1, y2, y3], 'r', alpha = 0.5)
```

to remove it you can than use:

```
for f in filled:
    f.remove()
```

see the minimum example below:

```
fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x1, x2, x3 = 1, 2, 3
y1, y2, y3 = 0, 2, 0

fill = ax.fill([x1, x2, x3], [y1, y2, y3], 'r', alpha = 0.5)

ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

fig.savefig('test1.png')

for f in fill:
    f.remove()

fig.savefig('test2.png')
```

test1.png:
[image: before removal]

test2.png:
[image: after removal]

PS: when adding the figure, is generally best to use the built-in constructors such as `plt.subplots` or `plt.figure` instead of accessing the class directly as in `Figure`